# Does Blazor have some mechanism working like $attrs in vue?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

I found that $attrs in vue is a very helpful thing in component design. If I have a component wrapping an "a" tag, I could use $attrs to pass in all those native props without claiming them as parameters one by one. For example, I have a component like this:

```
<div>
    <a href="@Href" onclick="@OnClick" class="@Classes" style="@Styles">@Content</a>
</div>
```

I have to declare parameters of "Href, OnClick, Classes, Styles" and so forth. But we know that tag "a" has huge amount of other attributes, like "target, hreflang...", not to mention "input" tag or so. I think it's stupid to claim all of them as a unbelievable long parameter list.

So dose Blazor provide such similar function for us developers?

Comment: onclick is not an attribute. It is a directive, and should be preceded by the @ token. Passing a collection of parameters has been possible, I think, from the very beginning. But now you can use the @attributes directive to pass a collection of parameters to an element or a component.

Comment: Well, thank you very much. I should have followed thees new features.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, it does.

You can use Blazor’s new [‘splat’ operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/core/blazor/components?view=aspnetcore-3.0#attribute-splatting-and-arbitrary-parameters) to do this. For example:

```html
// MyComp

<div id=“@Id” @attributes=“InputAttributes”></div>

@code {
    [Parameter] 
    public string Id { get; set; } 

    [Parameter(CaptureUnmatchedValues = true)]
    public Dictionary<string, object> InputAttributes { get; set; }
}
```

Defining a parameter per the example above will make it collect any attributes defined on the component which don’t match any existing declared parameters.

Usage:

```html
<MyComp Id=“foo” class=“myclass” />
```

Would render:

```html
<div id=“foo” class=“myclass”></div>
```

Comment: That what I need. Thank you for the detail.

Comment: @SillyJumper Would you mind marking it as the answer if it solved your problem, so others know it was useful.

Comment: Of course, I'm sorry, I even googled how to mark an anwser. I think that's why I am a silly Jumper...

Comment: In case it confused anyone, the html `id` attribute (all lowercase) could have also just been put directly in the Razor component tag without using the Id (capital "I") member Parameter in the @code block. So in other words, you'd get the same result by: first, in the razor component file, remove `id="@Id"` from the html `<div>` component, and then also remove the member Parameter Id from the @code block. Then when using it, just specify the `id` attribute like a normal html attribute, just like is being done with the `class` attribute. So: `<MyComp id="foo" class="myClass" />`.

Comment: This is what i was looking for

Answer (score 6):

Yes, from the [ASP.NET blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/asp-net-core-and-blazor-updates-in-net-core-3-0-preview-7/)

> #Accepting arbitrary parameters
> To define a component that accepts
> arbitrary attributes define a component parameter using the
> [Parameter] attribute with the CaptureUnmatchedValues property set to
> true. The type of the parameter must be assignable from
> Dictionary<string, object>. This means that
> IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>> or
> IReadOnlyDictionary<string, object> are also options.

```
@code {
     [Parameter(CaptureUnmatchedValues= true)]
     public Dictionary<string, object> Attributes { get; set; } 
}
```

> The CaptureUnmatchedValues property on [Parameter] allows that parameter
> to match all attributes that do not match any other parameter. A
> component can only define a single parameter with
> CaptureUnmatchedValues.
>
> ## Using @attributes to render arbitrary attributes
>
> A component can pass
> arbitrary attributes to another component or markup element using the
> @attributes directive attribute. The @attributes directive allows you
> to specify a collection of attributes to pass to a markup element or
> component. This is valuable because the set of key-value-pairs
> specified as attributes can come from a .NET collection and do not
> need to be specified in the source code of the component.

`<input class="form-field" @attributes="Attributes" type="text" />`

```
@code {
    [Parameter(CaptureUnmatchedValues = true)]
    public Dictionary<string, object> Attributes { get; set; } 
}
```

> Using the @attributes directive the contents of the Attribute property get
> “splatted” onto the input element. If this results in duplicate
> attributes, then evaluation of attributes occurs from left to right.
> In the above example if Attributes also contained a value for class it
> would supersede class="form-field". If Attributes contained a value
> for type then that would be superseded by type="text".

Comment: Yes, I appreciate that developers of Blazor always can catch up with our needs.